# Tag incorrectly enumerated as MIFARE Classic, SAK = 32

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I have a Sony Xperia Z3. I am using it to interact with MIFARE Classic smart cards.

When using a native MIFARE card, I'm able to read the card correctly.

However if I'm using a MIFARE Classic emulated, I get a SAK that is not correct. In stead of 0x38 I get 0x20 (32) and the following error when using  `MifareClassic.get(tag)`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Tag incorrectly enumerated as MIFARE Classic, SAK = 32
```

I don't know why my mobile incorrectly reads the SAK.

The same card is correctly read on other devices supporting MIFARE as a Nexus S, etc.

Any idea why this exception?

TA

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this patch as `tag = cleanupTag(tag)` before calling `MifareClassic.get(tag)`
For more information read [MifareClassicTool Sony Z3 issue](https://github.com/ikarus23/MifareClassicTool/issues/64)

```
private Tag cleanupTag(Tag oTag){
    if (oTag == null)
        return null;

    String[] sTechList = oTag.getTechList();

    Parcel oParcel = Parcel.obtain();
    oTag.writeToParcel(oParcel, 0);
    oParcel.setDataPosition(0);

    int len = oParcel.readInt();
    byte[] id = null;
    if (len >= 0) {
        id = new byte[len];
        oParcel.readByteArray(id);
    }
    int[] oTechList = new int[oParcel.readInt()];
    oParcel.readIntArray(oTechList);
    Bundle[] oTechExtras = oParcel.createTypedArray(Bundle.CREATOR);
    int serviceHandle = oParcel.readInt();
    int isMock = oParcel.readInt();
    IBinder tagService;
    if (isMock == 0) {
        tagService = oParcel.readStrongBinder();
    } else {
        tagService = null;
    }
    oParcel.recycle();

    int nfca_idx = -1;
    int mc_idx = -1;
    short oSak = 0;
    short nSak = 0;

    for (int idx = 0; idx < sTechList.length; idx++) {
        if (sTechList[idx].equals(NfcA.class.getName())) {
            if (nfca_idx == -1) {
                nfca_idx = idx;
                if (oTechExtras[idx] != null
                        && oTechExtras[idx].containsKey("sak")) {
                    oSak = oTechExtras[idx].getShort("sak");
                    nSak = oSak;
                }
            } else {
                if (oTechExtras[idx] != null
                        && oTechExtras[idx].containsKey("sak")) {
                    nSak = (short) (nSak | oTechExtras[idx].getShort("sak"));
                }
            }
        } else if (sTechList[idx].equals(MifareClassic.class.getName())) {
            mc_idx = idx;
        }
    }

    boolean modified = false;

    if (oSak != nSak) {
        oTechExtras[nfca_idx].putShort("sak", nSak);
        modified = true;
    }

    if (nfca_idx != -1 && mc_idx != -1 && oTechExtras[mc_idx] == null) {
        oTechExtras[mc_idx] = oTechExtras[nfca_idx];
        modified = true;
    }

    if (!modified) {
        return oTag;
    }

    Parcel nParcel = Parcel.obtain();
    nParcel.writeInt(id.length);
    nParcel.writeByteArray(id);
    nParcel.writeInt(oTechList.length);
    nParcel.writeIntArray(oTechList);
    nParcel.writeTypedArray(oTechExtras, 0);
    nParcel.writeInt(serviceHandle);
    nParcel.writeInt(isMock);
    if (isMock == 0) {
        nParcel.writeStrongBinder(tagService);
    }
    nParcel.setDataPosition(0);

    Tag nTag = Tag.CREATOR.createFromParcel(nParcel);

    nParcel.recycle();

    return nTag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The tag is detected and SAK is the correct one. But the problem is that when we try to read the memory from the Mifare card we got an exception that the tag is lost. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The SAK value is not a magic value that you could use to distinguish different NFC tags. Instead it is a bit masked value that defines some capabilities of the RF protocol.

Unfortunately the google Android code uses the SAK for mifare card identification as you can see in this code here: [MifareClassic.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic.java)

What happens in your Xperia Z3 is probably that the NFC controller and NFC stack correctly detect the tag as Mifare compatible and report it as such. Once you try to use the tag you run into the problems you've mentioned.

The Nexus S is likely running a fixed version of the MifareClassic.java code and avoids the problem.

What can you do about it: From an application perspective nothing really. It's a bug in the Android OS. If you have root access you could do it the hard way and patch the member function on the fly.

Comment: The SAK helps you to know what type of protocol can be used with the card. The fact here is that the Z3 is the only mobile I have tested the card that is returning a SAK with that value (0x20). Actually the SAK is generated by the card on response to the Select command, so every mobile/chipset should be returning the same value. Why the chip on the Z3 is doing it another way? This is the issue ;)